# create a cross tab (maybe/sort of, not sure what its called) with Python

Tags: python, arrays, csv, matrix

What I am trying to achieve is a csv file that looks like this:

```
,h.r9,h.r8,h.r5,h.r4,h.r7,h.r6,h.r1,h.r3,h.r2,h.r10
chris,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,0,0
bob,0,0,1,1,1,1,0,0,0,1
dick,1,0,1,0,0,0,0,0,1,1
ab,1,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0
emma,0,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0
```

*somewhat unrelated: does anyone know what the actual name for a matrix like this is? That would at least make googling this issue easier.*

The data is originally in a dictionary like this:

```
dict = {}
dict['ab'] = ["h.r1","h.r2"]
dict['bob'] = ["h.r3","h.r4","h.r5","h.r6","h.r10"]
dict['chris'] = ["h.r2","h.r8"]
dict['dick'] = ["h.r1","h.r10","h.r9","h.r3"]
dict['emma'] = ["h.r3","h.r5","h.r7","h.r9"]
```

So, if a person has the variable in the dictionary there should be a 1 in the CSV otherwise there should be a zero.

The code below builds the csv file, but with all zeros. How would I implement the logic of ones and zeros? I can do this in PHP/HTML, but being very new to Python I'm not not catching on... Also is there a library that may already have this function built in? (numpy perhaps?)

```
import csv

dict = {}
dict['ab'] = ["h.r1","h.r2"]
dict['bob'] = ["h.r3","h.r4","h.r5","h.r6","h.r10"]
dict['chris'] = ["h.r2","h.r8"]
dict['dick'] = ["h.r1","h.r10","h.r9","h.r3"]
dict['emma'] = ["h.r3","h.r5","h.r7","h.r9"]

mergedlist = []
for k,v in dict.items():
        mergedlist = mergedlist + v
mergedlist = list(set(mergedlist))
listlen = len(mergedlist)
mergedlist[0:0] = " "

thekeys = []
for k in dict.keys():
        thekeys.append(k)

thecsv = csv.writer(open("your.csv", 'w', newline=''))
thecsv.writerow(mergedlist)

for col in thekeys:
        thecsv.writerow([col] + ['0']*listlen) #does the logic go in here somehow??
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have no idea what most of that code is doing. It can be done in just a couple of lines:

```
all_values = set()
for person_values in data.values():
    all_values = all_values.union(person_values)
all_values_list = list(all_values)

thecsv = csv.writer(open("your.csv", 'w'))
thecsv.writerow(all_values_list)
for name, values in data.items():
    row = [1 if i in values else 0 for i in all_values_list]
    thecsv.writerow([name] + row)
```

Note I've renamed your dictionary to `data`, as it's not a good idea to overwrite built-in function/class names.

Comment: Thanks, I'm very new to Python (this is my first program ever) so there is some cool stuff in here, yes I need to figure list comprehensions. But, it doesn't work: It doesn't create a header row, and the logic seems to be broken. For example when I run this the "ab" row has `1,1,1,1,0,0,1,1,1,1`, when there should only be two ones in the entire row.

Comment: Sorry, had 0 and 1 mixed up, try it now.

Comment: awesome, works now! The only addition I made was to change `thecsv.writerow(all_values_list)` to `thecsv.writerow([''] + all_values_list)` so that there would be a blank cell at the top of the first column (I need this for the specific format that the next program that will use this file takes)

Answer (score 1):

I would do it completely different but using your code I'd change the `['0']*listlen` to:
`['1' if x in dict[col] else '0' for x in thekeys]`

Comment: As I said in my comment on the other post, this is my first Python program ever. So if there is another way you would do it, I'd be glad to hear it?

Answer (score 1):

First you don't want to name you data `dict` as it overrides `dictionary`, change it to something like `dict1`:

```
#first generate the data body:
>>> ar=[[dict1[jtem].count(item) for item in ['h.r%s' %i for i in range(1, 11)]] for jtem in dict1] #are your values only in h.s1 to h.s10?
>>> ar
[[0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], \
[1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], \
[0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
[1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
[0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
#Then insert the names:
>>> junk=[item.insert(0, jtem) for item, jtem in zip(ar, dict1.keys())]
>>> ar
[['chris', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], \
['dick', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], \
['bob', 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
['ab', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
['emma', 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
#Then insert the title:
>>> ar.insert(0, ['',]+['h.r%s' %i for i in range(1, 11)])
>>> ar
[['', 'h.r1', 'h.r2', 'h.r3', 'h.r4', 'h.r5', 'h.r6', 'h.r7', 'h.r8', 'h.r9', 'h.r10'], \
['chris', 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 0, 0], \
['dick', 1, 0, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1], \
['bob', 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 1], \
['ab', 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0], \
['emma', 0, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 0]]
```

Then write it to a CSV file using your favorite method.